# Marlin - G92 after bed levelling?

Tags: marlin, bed-leveling

In some of my G-code files the job X and Y start from 0, 0. I move the nozzle to where I want the print to start and then send `G92 X0 Y0 Z0` to the printer and only then start the job. This has worked really well for me so far.

I want to try and use the bilinear bed leveling feature in Marlin but on a specific area of the bed. Something like that:

```
G29 L47 R112 F14 B64
```

My question is - if after the `G29` command is finished and the probing is done, I then position the nozzle at `X47` and `Y14`, and then send the command `G92 X0 Y0` (without Z), would that interfere with the bed leveling or would it work ok?